# scrollviewdidendzooming not getting called

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am implementing zoom in / out and I can not understand why  `scrollviewdidendzooming` delegate function not getting called.

here is my code.  I am in confused `viewForZoomingInScrollView` function is called but `scrollviewdidendzooming` not.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    _contentProgramsView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _contentProgramsView.tag = 9999;
    [_contentProgramsView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5*9*self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+400);
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 2.0f;
    _scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _scrollView setBouncesZoom:YES];
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    _scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [_scrollView viewWithTag:9999];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    //set the scrolling bounds
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

_scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
_scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 2.0f;

The maximumZoomScale needs to be greater than the minimumZoomScale.
Fixing this should work but if it doesn't, add _scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

I hope this helps.